# Grails: Can't access set of hasMany Relation (No such property)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails

I'm currently working on the unit tests for the domain classes I've built. But for some reason I can't access the elements in the 'hasMany' realation.

When I try to access the property 'module.exams' it throws an exception groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: exams for class: ch.fhnw.webec.Module.

I've seen countless examples where people access the property. I tried exams, getExams, addTo etc. but none works.

```java
void 'test module relation'() {

    Teacher teacher = new Teacher(prename: "Max", surname: "Mustermann")
    Module module = new Module(name: "Workshop 1", shortName: "WS2", credits: 3, year: 2019, isSpring: true, teacher: teacher)

    Exam exam1 = new Exam(module: module, name: "PrÃ¼efung 01", isMsp: false, number: 1, weight: 1, date: Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2019-03-28"))
    Exam exam2 = new Exam(module: module, name: "PrÃ¼efung 01", isMsp: false, number: 1, weight: 1, date: Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2019-03-28"))

    expect:
    module.exams.count() == 2 // <--  this line
}



package ch.fhnw.webec

class Module {
// ....
    static hasMany = [exams: Exam]
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through try an error and tons of question on the internet I found a solution. Instead of deleting the question I thought I'd explain the solution. Maybe this can help others that try to figure this out as well:

Thanks to JeffScottBrown for pointing that out:
By default it creates a set. Which means addToXXX does work.
But for in my case I needed a list and this is what I had to add:

```java
 class Module {
    static hasMany = [exams: Exam]
    List exams
    // ...
}
```

But adding those isn't enough. When creating the objects you have to add them to this list via the generated 'addToXY' method:

```java
    module.addToExams(exam1)
    module.addToExams(exam2)

    assert module.exams.size() == 2
```

Comment: In fact, you can skip setting the module on the exam during initialization when you do it this way.  Using addToXXX is how you set up two-way relationships

Comment: "In order to access these objects, a List Property is needed as well" - That is incorrect.  By default you will get a `Set` property.  You only hav etc declare the `List` property if you want to use a `List` instead of a `Set`.

Comment: But when I remember correctly, I wasn't able to add anything because I got the message that the method 'addToXXX' doesn't exist. So even if it is a set, I should be able to access the set or add Items to it, right?

I'll check it in evening to be sure.

Comment: So I testet it and @JeffScottBrown you were actualy right. It creates a set. Thanks for that input